# Docker mounting container volume as read only

Tags: docker, bamboo

I'm using Bamboo to run my CI. It invokes docker by this command:

```
/usr/bin/docker run --volume /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1:/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1 --volume /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp:/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp --detach --net=host --name e21094b5-2f97-4cee-b44b-912cdb0091a52621443 shamilnunhuck/terraform:0.13.5 tail -f /dev/null
```

I can see that the mount is read-only?

```
10.24.71.11:/zpool-127609/data/conductor/agents/0/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1 on /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/INFRA-CFDNS-JOB1 type nfs (ro,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.24.71.11,mountvers=3,mountport=34755,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.24.71.11)
```

Can someone tell me how the volume is read-only from the docker run point of view?

Comment: It may help you with that - [link](https://dille.name/blog/2018/07/16/handling-file-permissions-when-writing-to-volumes-from-docker-containers/)

Comment: That output looks like there's an NFS mount on your host (maybe in `/etc/fstab`) that's read-only; I don't think it's related to anything you're doing in Docker, and I don't think Docker's specifically aware of it.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, so I have a DIND setup, with the bamboo agent running in Kubernetes. On the bamboo agent container, the directory is rw, but only in the child container created is the volume ro

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  It seems like your setup is significantly more involved than the `docker run` command you list here.